# Applicative style parser for constructor with two arguments

Tags: haskell, parsec, applicative

I want to write a parser for a comma separated pair of values in angle brackets. I got it to work with the following approach:

```
pair p1 p2 = do
    x1 <- p1
    comma
    x2 <- p2
    return (x1, x2)

data Foo = Foo (Bar, Bar)

foo :: Parser Foo
foo = Foo <$> (angles $ pair bar bar)
```

However I would prefer the Foo constructor to take two parameter rather than a tuple:

```
data Foo = Foo Bar Bar
```

What is the best way to write such a parser? Ideally I would like to reuse standard Parsec parsers such a `angles` and use applicative as much as possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the best way to write such a parser? Ideally I would like to reuse standard Parsec parsers such a angles and use applicative as much as possible.

In applicative style, your parser would be

```
foo = angles $ Foo <$> bar <* comma <*> bar
```

Going inside out, a `bar` is parsed, then a `comma`, which is discarded, and another `bar`, then the constructor `Foo` is applied to the two parsed `bar`s. Finally, all is wrapped into the `angles` combinator, so that a string of the form

```
< bar , bar >
```

is parsed (`bar` should probably consume trailing whitespace).

Combining parsers ignoring the result of one with the `*>` and `<*` applicative combinators eliminates the need for the `pair` combinator and easily generalises to constructors taking an arbitrary number of arguments.

As [C.A. McCann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157360/c-a-mccann) mentioned in a comment, the `(<$)` combinator (which is part of GHC's implementation of the `Functor` class, with the default implementation `(<$) = fmap . const`; but it's not part of the language standard) is useful too, if you want to ignore a leading token. Using that, you can write

```
Foo <$ ignoreMe <*> bar <* comma <*> baz
```

which is nicer than using parentheses

```
Foo <$> (ignoreMe *> bar) <* comma <*> baz
```

or `pure`,

```
pure Foo <* ignoreMe <*> bar <* comma <*> baz
```

as would be required in some form without it.

Comment: Also, for the case where you have a leading token to ignore, you can use something like `Foo <$ keywordFoo <*> bar <* comma <*> baz`. I forget where `(<$)` is defined and what exports it, though.

Comment: ``class Functor f where   ...  (<$) :: a -> f b -> f a -- Defined in `GHC.Base' infixl 4 <$`` Good point, that is useful too.